# If $5 * 5$ = $10$ , $6*6$ = $18$ , $7*7$ = $36$ ; then $7* 8$ =?

Tags: puzzle, pattern-recognition

> If $$\quad 5 * 5 = 10$$ ,
>    $$\quad 6*6=18$$
>   $$\quad 7*7=36$$
>    then $$\quad 7* 8 = ?$$

a) $54 \quad$ b) $51 \quad$ c) $30$

NOTE: Here '$*$' is not simple multiplication
It is some logic or combinations of operations  from which we are getting $10$ from $5$ and $5$
Similarly, we are getting the rest of the relations via the same logic or combinations of operations

My Thoughts:
$$10= 5*(5-3)$$
i.e, LOGIC: $\quad x* (x-3) = $ RHS
Similarly $2nd$ relation is satisfied, i.e,
$$18=6*(6-3)$$
$$\text{But, } 36 \neq 7 * (7-3)$$
So, how to solve this puzzle? Any Suggestions please...

Comment: All of 3 can be correct.

Comment: How? Can you please explain...

Comment: The $*$ function is not well defined, so $7*8$ can be anything.

Comment: "$*$ is not well defined" , I agreed; but in this problem that is what required to be find. For eg.: '$*$' should be defined in such a way that it satisfies given $3$ relations, and then that definition of '$*$' should be used to evaluate $7*8$

Comment: But you can't give an unique extension with the given conditions. You can let, for example $5*5=10, 6*6=18,7*7=36$ and $0$ otherwise. Why would any other extension be better or worse than this one?

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion:
Let $ab=10x+y$. Then $a*b=f(x,y)$.

Comment: Sorry i could not understand, could you please explain how we can relate $10x + y  \, $  with $5*5=10$ ?